# How can I scroll down in this window provided by Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

In Eclipse's Android plugin, I'm trying to create a new project, however the window won't let me scroll down.  Is there a way to fix this?  Note the image attached.

http://www.matthewhaworth.net/screenshot.png

Comment: pressing `tab` doesn't work?

Comment: No it doesn't : [.  I think it puts the cursor in the box, but the box is still not visible

Comment: updating eclipse or android may help.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the scroll overlay. Eclipse based products still doesn't know how to deal with this relatively new feature of Ubuntu.
Add the following before the eclipse command. Run it by invoking `LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 eclipse`.

Answer (score 0):

From developing own RCP applications I've recognized, that the preference dialog sometimes behaves in a strange way (the calculated size does not match the real one), but at least I'm able to scroll and so on.
Have you ever tried to simply resize the window?

BTW: Which version of the tool do you use? My "ne Android Project" wizard looks a little bit different (the target has to be defined on a separate page)